# Python script -- permission errors

Tags: package-management, permissions, scripts, python, repository

I'm trying to run a python script (https://github.com/swiss-chris/quora-expander) on Ubuntu 20.04.3, but the terminal returns an error.

My input:

```
python3 /home/kitezh/quora-expander/quora-expander.py Dima-Vorobiev
```

The terminal response:

```
opening https://www.quora.com/profile/Dima-Vorobiev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kitezh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: PosixPath('/home/kitezh/chromedriver')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kitezh/quora-expander/quora-expander.py", line 113, in <module>
    browser = connectchrome()
  File "/home/kitezh/quora-expander/quora-expander.py", line 20, in connectchrome
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
  File "/home/kitezh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/kitezh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

How do I fix this? Thank you for your time.

UPD:

> Did you do as the message says and "see
> sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"? What did that say?

That's where I downloaded ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 from in the first place.

> Also, what is the output of ls -l /home/kitezh/chromedriver?

Here it is:

```
total 11908
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kitezh kitezh 12192312 Aug 28 02:00 chromedriver
```

> Does that file exist? Is it executable?

When I input `chromedriver`, here's the terminal response.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

> Does package require chrome to be installed? If so when you type
> google-chrome at the command line does it startup without any
> permission errors?

Yes, the package requires chrome.
Google Chrome launches, but the terminal outputs the following:

```
[3050:3050:0912/051629.264392:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(162)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[3113:3113:0912/051629.941247:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(162)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[3165:3165:0912/051629.979258:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[3005:3042:0912/051728.670790:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(848)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
```

@waltinator

> Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with
> https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script.

I've run this script, and here are the results.
My input: `$ pathlld /usr/bin/chromedriver`

The terminal output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 10 17:53 /
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
drwxrwxrwx 14 root root 4096 Aug 19 16:32 /usr
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 45056 Sep 12 13:48 /usr/bin
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kitezh kitezh 12192312 Aug 28 02:00 /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding something, but why the `//` when specifying the file?

Comment: @matigo Mistake on my part.
Original post updated with correct input and the terminal response to it.

Comment: Did you do as the message says and "see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"? What did that say? Also, what is the output of `ls -l /home/kitezh/chromedriver`? Does that file exist? Is it executable? Please [edit] your question and add the answers.

Comment: Does package require chrome to be installed? If so when you type `google-chrome` at the command line does it startup without any permission errors?

Comment: @terdon I've added answers to the original post.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Answers added to the original post.

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script.